# Add images to d3 chord diagram

Tags: javascript, d3.js, chord-diagram

I would like images as the endpoints. I have tried adding  but no luck. Any ideas/working examples?

http://bost.ocks.org/mike/uberdata/

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Each neighborhood in that example is given a `<g>` element with a class of `group`.

```
// Add a group per neighborhood.
var group = svg.selectAll(".group")
    .data(layout.groups)
  .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "group")
    .on("mouseover", mouseover);
```

This is the element to which the text label and the endpoint path are appended.

```
// Add the group arc.
var groupPath = group.append("path")
    .attr("id", function(d, i) { return "group" + i; })
    .attr("d", arc)
    .style("fill", function(d, i) { return cities[i].color; });

// Add a text label.
var groupText = group.append("text")
    .attr("x", 6)
    .attr("dy", 15);
```

You could append each image to this group also, using an svg [`<image>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/image) element. If, for example, your dataset contains the urls for your images, you might do the following:

```
var groupImage = group.append("image")
  .attr("xlink:href", function(d) {return d.image_url;})
```

Comment: You're not setting a size for the images or providing a location where they should go. I was suggesting a general approach to the problem, not providing a copy-and-paste solution. You'll need to include attributes for width, height, and transform to size and position your images in addition to the xlink:href.